# How to upload file in firebase cloud function into firebase storage from url?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm using some API, that can give me file with 2 ways:

```
- I can get FILE in response
- I can get direct URL to the file to download
```

I decided to make request with first method, get FILE in response. I'm trying to save the file in firebase storage, from firebase cloud function:

```
exports.test = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const axios = require('axios').default

  axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `https://cloudpbx.beeline.ru/apis/portal/v2/records/06365a27-f8d1-4c51-bba3-a08802429964/9052948777%40mpbx.sip.beeline.ru/download`
  }).then((resp) => {
    console.log('resp', resp.data)

    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('cardbox-1.appspot.com/mcun/calls')
    bucket.upload(resp.data)
  })
})
```

In `resp.data` i have something like that:

```
��H�Xing��h  $&)+-.179:>ACEGINRTW[_acegjmoqtwz|����������������������������������������������������PLAME3.100(,�$!��h�6���H��V]@mdE�E��"@���}�8kwT��&���>:P�2��>?�����8 ����������*���Z��XVC�(b�k�
D�G��
```

As i can see its file by itself, but how to handle it, and how upload it into firebase storage? Also, i'm not sure, that i'm correct creating a bucket and using storage api.

**Please feel free to make request, you can get response without auth. That file must be mp3 type**

Here is the logs with headers about what i'm getting from response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Tue, 24 Mar 2020 16:19:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 48744
Connection: close
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.mp3

��H�Xing��h  $&)+-.179:>ACEGINRTW[_acegjmoqtwz|����������������������������������������������������PLAME3.100(,�$!��h�6���H��V]@mdE�E��"@���}�8kwT��&���>:P�2��>?�����8 ����������*���Z��XVC�(b�k�
D�G��
C���al�ꝰ�z�KY�Q�]ЪF�8�^���W;,�LUteA�%�u�&��.���
0�q��Cڟ#���6��@�K�h��Itᠠ|[�q�{j'�+  �ʤS<F�  Y�5D]?�����nlƦBC�S�Zx'�e�D�Fi_��Vl��4����H��E�z���SMVПQ�P� AT<���(�x�+3�ТB����e�ZC}t��Ї�#֗����2���Kve���.�ԏ�UH���u����ʘfbC��C� ��C�+ġ��̺��R#��|x5hq`Х3�?�N(���.5��� c+��`�Y�F8�d�B&53��¥�L�cx4��3��q�JHԓJ�43Ώ�(к�4r ��a �D
Dɍ0�
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it seems that there are a couple of tasks to do here :)

According to the definition of the [upload method](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload) and their examples, using node js as client library (that makes total sense). You will be able to Upload a file to the bucket. But to be honest, I am not very clear about the usage of the pathString parameter since it points to a local path. Maybe the URL option that you mentioned would be great to test as a feature.

Just pasting the example from docs:

```
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  async function uploadFile() {
    // Uploads a local file to the bucket
    await storage.bucket(bucketName).upload(filename, {
      gzip: true,
      metadata: {            
        Content-Type: 'audio/mpeg'            
      },
    });

        console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
  }

  uploadFile().catch(console.error);
```

Another way to accomplish this, is to make a POST request with the [JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) to the upload method of Cloud Storage. As I understand, the objects are [saved](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) as "RAW" in Cloud Storage.

If you are concerned about the conversion to MP3 file, I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56358921/converting-audio-file-when-uploaded-to-google-cloud-storage) explains very well. Basically, if you want to perform the conversion in the Firebase Function, maybe is not the best scenario according to the size/time of the files.

Good Luck!